# What's the deal with HTTP status code 308?

Tags: http-status-codes, rfc, http-status-code-308

An IETF RFC draft [The Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Status Code 308 (Permanent Redirect)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-reschke-http-status-308-07) defines HTTP status 308 as **Permanent Redirect**. It should, of course, be noted that this is a draft document and contains in its document header the text "Expires: September 27, 2012", which I presume would mean it should be considered invalid now, but I'm not familiar with IETF's processes and so don't feel confident about this.

The Wikipedia article [List of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) uses this definition of 308, also:

> **308 Permanent Redirect (approved as experimental [RFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments))<sup>[12]</sup>**
>
> > The request, and all future requests should be repeated using another URI. 307 and 308 (as proposed) parallel the behaviours of 302 and 301, but *do not allow the HTTP method to change*. So, for example, submitting a form to a permanently redirected resource may continue smoothly.
>
> ...
>
> [12]: ["The Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Status Code 308 (Permanent Redirect)"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-reschke-http-status-308). [IETF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF). 2012. Retrieved March 27, 2012.

Eric Law, of Microsoft at the time, comments on this HTTP/308 code in [Pushing the Web Forward with HTTP/308](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/29/http-308-permanent-redirect-pushing-the-web-forward-by-breaking-unwanted-forward-compatibility.aspx). That caused me to discover that Firefox supports 308 under this meaning.

However, when I was looking in the [python-requests](/questions/tagged/python-requests) library, I found that there is another usage of 308:

```
    308: ('resume_incomplete', 'resume'),
```

This seems to come from a Google Gears [resumable HTTP requests proposal](http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/ResumableHttpRequestsProposal), defining `308 Resume Incomplete`. There seems to be some usage of that. Of course, neither of these proposals acknowledges the existence of the other.

So what's going on? Is `308 Permanent Redirect` alive? What's happening with the status code 308? What should I do?

Comment: Are you asking, from a server perspective, whether you should *issue* a 308 (and if so, under what circumstances), or from a consumer perspective how you should *react* to a 308?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: the question is mostly wondering what's happening with it, is it meaningful, *can* I reasonably use it. In my particular case, I am dealing with the client perspective, wishing to make a future-ready and correct implementation of this and related matters, but I'm also seeking more general information to try to gather it a little - there's not much on it on the web.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Internet Draft has not expired (as it was approved before it expired). See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-reschke-http-status-308/ and http://www.rfc-editor.org/queue2.html#draft-reschke-http-status-308 for the current publication status.

Comment: So that means it's been approved but is hanging around waiting for the editors to get to it? What does that mean about 308 in the mean time? That using it as Permanent Redirect would be "invalid"? Then too, what exactly does being approved as an *experimental* RFC mean?

Comment: It is approved, and it is a registered status code. It's just that the RFC won't be published until the other documents that it references are.

Answer (score 2):

Please see Chris Morgan comment below on this question (my original answer referred to  http://insanecoding.blogspot.co.il/2014/02/http-308-incompetence-expected.html?m=1 but Chris' reference is much better).

Just to get a sense how far 308 has not gone yet, see the HTTP codes defined in Microsoft's .NET framework V4 ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ) the HttpStatusCode enumeration). Specifically, no mention of code 308.

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7249193 has good comments on the article—the article is well meant but itself does not understand the full situation.

Comment: 307 is now in the msdn article you linked to, but still not 308