# Trying to match a partial url, then strip the question mark and everthing after

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to match a url like this:

https://domainname.com/blog/entry/blog-post-alias?fbclid=IwAR2qsvsMxGmTzqFuqggJV53uLpgCEi9dMSRj-jdERfVS2ndJq8Sya70XD48

and strip it so it redirects to:
https://domainname.com/blog/entry/blog-post-alias

There are nearly 200 post like this so I can't match on the post alias, but I do know they are ALWAYS at /blog/entry/

Also I can't just strip off everything after the ? for the entire site as it'll break search queries.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the specific match I wanted has already been done in another answer:

[What is fbclid? the new facebook parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52847475/what-is-fbclid-the-new-facebook-parameter)