# why does a file path appear after my domain on my home page?

Tags: url, redirect

When I click a link to my webstore, it redirects the URLand adds a giant file path after my domain. Should be thefantomcase.com but when you click the link its URL shows https://thefantomcase.com/?fbclid=IwAR3Zor-D4paelHuoMm-52E_usErS9YtpMXQKqr9QIKwuY5X0Rn8ThiAltZI
Why is this happening?

tried using a bitly link which changed nothing

Comment: The question mark would after the / would usually indicate the beginning of a query parameter. You can add stuff here to any website and it will stay as long as the website doesn't explicitly remove it from the page when it loads (Ex: https://www.google.com/?asdfasdf ) or there is no redirections. You should include an example of where the link is generated/found and loosely how the web store is constructed (ex with shopify using x). To me, It looks like something ( a tool or plugin perhaps) is appending information to track your link.

Comment: https://thefantomcase.com/
Made with shopify. When I click the link it ads the file path after but should not be there. Is it because of the bitly link? Or because of my apps on shopify? Facebook wont approve my ads because of the landing page and I have a hypothesis that that is why

Comment: After a bit more review it seems that everything after the link is being added to by facebook. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52847475/what-is-fbclid-the-new-facebook-parameter or https://thisinterestsme.com/facebook-fbclid-parameter/ . When I go to your website directly or through the link you just provided I do not see everything after the ? character in the url . Apparently facebook is adding it to outbound links (so if you click a link from facebook it will add the following characters in some situations).  There may be a shopify plugin to remove it. PS it's not a file path.